# Share dir between host and multiple containers using docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have 2 containers in a compose files,that i want to serve app static files through nginx.

I have read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43560093/7522096 and want to use host dir to share between app container and nginx container, for some reason I dont want to use named volume.

===

> Using a host directory Alternately you can use a directory on the host
>   and mount that into the containers. This has the advantage of you
>   being able to work directly on the files using your tools outside of
>   Docker (such as your GUI text editor and other tools).
>
> It's the same, except you don't define a volume in Docker, instead
>   mounting the external directory.

```
version: '3' 
services:   
   nginx:
    volumes:
     - ./assets:/var/lib/assets   
   asset:
    volumes:
     - ./assets:/var/lib/assets
```

===

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    env_file:
      - ./env/app.env
    image: registry.gitlab.com/app/development
    volumes:
      - ./public/app/:/usr/app/static/
      - app-log:/root/.pm2

  nginx:
      container_name: nginx
      image: 'nginx:1.16-alpine'
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
      volumes:
        - /home/devops/config/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
        - /home/devops/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl:ro
        - ./public/app/:/etc/nginx/public/app/
      depends_on:
        - app
volumes:
  # app-public:
  app-log:
```

Yet when i do this in my compose, the dir always come up empty on nginx, and the static files in my app container got disappear too.

Please help, I tried a lot of ways but can not figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you put what you actually have in your docker-compose.yml for nginx and app containers? The snippet as posted is confusing (missing new lines, random `asset:`, multiple column definitions for single service.

Comment: I added my docker-compose file as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the initialization of the container docker will bind the `./public/app` directory on the host with the `/usr/app/static/` directory in the container.
If the `./public/app` does not exist it will be created. The bind is from the host to the container, meaning that the content of `./public/app` folder is 
reflected (copied) into the container and not viceversa. That's why after the initialization the static app directory is empty.

If my understanding is correct your goal is to share the application files between the app container and `nginx`.

Taken into consideration the above the only solution is to create the files in the volume after the volume is created. Here is an example for the relevant parts:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
      - ./public/app/:/usr/app/static_copy/
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: >
        -c "mkdir /usr/app/static;
        touch /usr/app/static/shared_file;
        mv /usr/app/static/* /usr/app/static_copy;
        rm -r /usr/app/static;
        ln -sfT /usr/app/static_copy/ /usr/app/static; 
        exec sleep infinity"

  nginx:
      image: 'nginx:1.16-alpine'
      volumes:
        - ./public/app/:/etc/nginx/public/app/
      depends_on:
        - app
```

This will move the static files to the `static_copy` directory and link back those files to `/usr/app/static`. Those files will be shared with the host (`public/app` director)
and `nginx` container (`/etc/nginx/public/app/`). Adapt it to fit your needs.

In alternative you can of course use named volumes.
Hope it helps