# docker compose how to mount the sys proc folder from one container to another

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

so I come across a way to share volumes amongst containers such as this [Docker compose how to mount path from one to another container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559619/docker-compose-how-to-mount-path-from-one-to-another-container)
but in the grafana example I am trying to follow

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/send-data/metrics/metrics-prometheus/prometheus-config-examples/docker-compose-linux/

the node-exporter image actually uses the sys proc folder of host linux machine as mount, not a data volume that is shared in my case my host linux machine would be another docker container, so is there anyway to do like

```
volumes:
  - /containername/proc:/host/proc:ro
  - /containername/sys:/host/sys:ro
  - /containername/:/rootfs:ro
```

in the given example it is assumed host machine is linux and where the app and metrics are running on

```
 volumes:
  - /proc:/host/proc:ro
  - /sys:/host/sys:ro
  - /:/rootfs:ro
```

since my host machine is not linux and I actually want to node-exporter to export the metrics from another docker container?